# converting milliseconds value to date?

Tags: java, date, time

consider the followign code:

```
public void convertTime()
{
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Date date;
    Date date2;

    date = df.parse("15/01/2010 21:58:54");
    date.getTime();                     //produces 1263585534000

    date2 = new Date(date.getTime());  //this is ok, compiles
    date2 = new Date(1263585534000);   //gives an error: The literal 1263585534000 of type int is out of range
}
```

I wonder how can i convert this long number into date format and why am i getting this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1263585534000 is bigger than 2^31-1. Use `L` to indicate a Long.

```
date2 = new Date(1263585534000L);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quidk answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
date2 = new Date(1263585534000L);
```

ending with L for long literal to indicate it is a long number.